# Python, scrape dynamic PDF

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a question regarding **scraping** of pdf documents from website, unfortunately, this isn't as simple as I thought, as the pdf document is embedded as a section of the website, and it is a dynamic pdf.

Example below:
**https://www.morningstar.co.uk/uk/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F000011J7K&tab=14&DocumentId=7967b8f6f4115dce4464b808254383b5&Format=PDF** -> this is where the pdf is.

The above address is in fact obtained from another page:
https://www.morningstar.co.uk/uk/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F000011J7K&tab=12 this page, where if you click the pdf button, it will take you to the bolded address.

Apologies for not having any code as I'm not sure even on how to start.

Answer (score 0):

Your web scraper has identified your target **tab=12 ??** from

```
https://www.morningstar.co.uk/uk/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F000011J7K&tab=12
```

as leading to the **5 th of 5 tabs tab=14 ??** *Document.PDF*

```
https://www.morningstar.co.uk/uk/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F000011J7K&tab=14&DocumentId=7967b8f6f4115dce4464b808254383b5&Format=PDF
```

which is later translated in an iFrame to

```
https://doc.morningstar.com/document/7967b8f6f4115dce4464b808254383b5.msdoc/?clientid=euretailsite
```

I dont know how you process from step 2 to 3 but we can clearly see if we enter into a reader our target **DocumentId=7967b8f6f4115dce4464b808254383b5**
to download by using `https://doc.morningstar.com/document/7967b8f6f4115dce4464b808254383b5.msdoc`  we get [image]

1. load 1st page of 100
2. find last of the tabs with DocumentId
3. read the ID
4. download the doc with that ID
5. eat sleep read repeat.

Comment: There is a button on the page  https://www.morningstar.co.uk/uk/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F000011J7K&tab=12, clicking on which, will take you to the tab=14 link, hence why, https://www.morningstar.co.uk/uk/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F000011J7K&tab=14&DocumentId=7967b8f6f4115dce4464b808254383b5&Format=PDF

I notice that the link 'https://www.morningstar.co.uk/uk/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F000011J7K&tab=14&DocumentId=7967b8f6f4115dce4464b808254383b5&Format=PDF' is within the HTML code, what I don't know is how I can download the pdf , as I want to automate this for 100 of them